# Recursive Function Spell Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have the following problem with my code, it is a recursive function that what it does is to print a word by means of symbols of chemical elements of the periodic table, like H, He,Li, Be,B,C,etc. For example of word 'silver' prints it as 'SiLvEr', using the symbols mentioned above, but in my program there is a problem because there are symbols of chemical elements of one, two or three letters, then the program is created to first check with one letter, then with two and finally with three, but if the program checks with one letter and if the element exists, then it will no longer check with 2 and 3 letters, this is the program

```py
def spell_elements(palabra:str , lista:list):
    
    if palabra == "":
        return ""
    
    if palabra[0].capitalize() in lista:
        return palabra[0].capitalize() + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[0]), Elementos)
    
    if palabra[:2].capitalize() in lista:
        return palabra[:2].capitalize() + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[:2]), Elementos)
    
    if palabra[:3].capitalize() in lista:
        return palabra[:3].capitalize() + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[:3]), Elementos)
    
    else:
        return ""
```

En este caso para el ejemplo de silver tenemos:

```py
Elementos = ['H','He','Li','Be','B','C','N','O','F','Ne','Na','Mg','Al','Si','P','S','Cl','Ar','K','Ca',
             'Sc','Ti','V','Cr','Mn','Fe','Co','Ni','Cu','Zn','Ga','Ge','As','Se','Br','Kr','Rb','Sr',
             'Y','Zr','Nb','Mo','Tc','Ru','Rh','Pd','Ag','Cd','In','Sn','Sb','Te','I','Xe','Cs','Ba','La',
             'Ce','Pr','Nd','Pm','Sm','Eu','Gd','Tb','Dy','Ho','Er','Tm','Yb','Lu','Hf','Ta','W','Re','Os','Ir',
             'Pt','Au','Hg','Tl','Pb','Bi','Po','At','Rn','Fr','Ra','Ac','Th','Pa','U','Np','Pu','Am','Cm',
             'Bk','Cf','Es','Fm','Md','No','Lr','Rf','Db','Sg','Bh','Hs','Mt','Ds','Rg','Cn','Uut','Fl','Uup','Lv',
             'Uus','Uuo']
print(spell_elements('arsenic',  Elementos)
# Output -> Ars
```

So in this case it finds first the element 'Ar' in the list Elements, the second element takes it as 'S', but later it no longer enters to take two characters that would be 'Se' that if it is in the list of "Elements", then I wanted to see if there is some way for my function although there is an element in the list Elements but does not lead us to anything, check the other two conditions 'If' because it could be that some of them lead to the solution.

It must be something like

```py
print(spell_elements('arsenic', Elementos)
# Output -> ArSeNIC
```

Comment: A finite state transducer would be great for this. But probably also overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through all sizes for the first part and only return the result if the recursion can find a solution:

```
def spell_elements(S,symbols):
    for size in (1,2,3):                          # try each size
        prefix = S[:size].capitalize()            # get prefix
        if prefix not in symbols: continue        # not in symbols
        if len(S)==size: return prefix            # single symbol
        suffix = spell_elements(S[size:],symbols) # solution for rest
        if suffix: return prefix+suffix           # return full solution

print(spell_elements('arsenic',Elementos)) # ArSeNIC
```

*Note that this would probably be nicer if you checked the sizes in decreasing order (which would return `ArSeNiC`)*

Comment: Missing the `symbols` in the inner call. Otherwise great solution.